# Laravel change url paramaters in controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I have eCommerce systems with ads so I want to count every click from the ad card , so I add ad=true to check it in my controller. It counts fine and work smooth

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/product/3?ad=true

but the problem is that if the page has been refreshed it will count more and more , so I need a way to remove this parameter 
how can I do this. if there any way else I am open to suggestions

Comment: after processing the request, you need to redirect to a new url without the parameters.

Comment: it seems as a good idea but is there any ideas to change the `ad` value or remove it directly !!

Comment: @user10076385
If you want to use redirection, it will be like return redirect()->route('route.name', ['parameter' => 'value']);

Comment: You can use cookies here, store a variable which holds the information to count or to not count, every time your controller is called just check for that variable and do the counts. for more info see https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#cookies

Comment: I don't get how to store cookie from url ?

Comment: @Wreigh worked fine for me, if you want to answer please add it to accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon processing the request, you can just redirect to the same *route* without the parameters.

E.g.,

```
public function action(Request $request)
{
    /* Process the Request */
    return redirect('theRouteName');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
Route::get('/product/{id}', 'YourController@funciton');

public function multi_delete($id) {
    $count = Input::get('ad');
    // your code goes here
    \Redirect::route('product', $id)

}
```